# User and Security metadata

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for the information on snowflake account users and associated grants assigned to specific users. Is there any snowflake database view available which gives the information on access rights granted to specific users.

similar to the - "SHOW GRANTS to USER "

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Recently released are my two new favorite account usage share views, GRANTS_TO_USERS and GRANTS_TO_ROLES.  I find myself querying them about 10x a day now!

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_users.html

Note:  the account usage views may have some latency, the docs say these two could be as old as 2 hours old, but they are still extremely useful.  If you don't want to use these, you can do it the "old fashion" way with "SHOW GRANTS" type of commands, but there are restrictions on those, documented here: 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html